# Assembler - standard input and conversion

Tags: assembly, hex, ascii

I want my program to read characters from standard input and summed it up in `kodd`.

However, when I entered, eg. The value of 23, i saved the following ASCII value of the first character only, ie. 2 without 3

The second problem is how to convert the value stored in `kodd` to hex code?
Also how to initialize `esi` and `edi` properly
I think about `mov $kod, %edi`
but what about `esi`?

```html
data
        kod: .space 1000
        kodd: .long 0
        kod_roz = 10000

.text

        text: .ascii "Podaj ciag znakow zakoncz enterem"
        text_len = . -text




.align 32

SYSEXIT=1
SYSREAD=3
SYSWRITE=4
STDOUT=1
STDIN=0
EXIT_SUCCESS=0

.global _start

_start:
        mov $4, %eax
        mov $1, %ebx
        mov $text, %ecx
        mov $text_len, %edx
        int $0x80
s:
        mov $3, %eax
        mov $0, %ebx
        mov $kod, %ecx
        mov $kod_roz,  %edx
        int $0x80
        mov kod(%esi,1),%bl #poczatek
        cmp $'\n',%bl
        je koniec
petla:
        mov kod(%edi,1),%bl     #koniec
        add %ebx, kodd
        je s


fm:
        inc %edi
        jmp s
koniec:
        mov $1,%eax
        mov $0,%ebx
        int $0x80
```

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29578964/assembler-linux-x86-how-to-mul-variable

Comment: But i still dont know how to initialize esi or edi

Comment: Do you know what `mov kod(%esi,1), %bl` does?

Comment: I think it move first byte of kod source register to register bl part of ebx register?

Comment: It uses `%esi * 1` as an index off of `kod` and references the data located at that address and moves that data into `%bl`.

Comment: I still dont understand, this copy all data from kod to %bl or just part?Also how To navigate the entered string to change the character by character?

Comment: You need to read up a little on how assembly language works. I'd suggest doing a google search on "gas assembly language tutorial" or "gas assembly language syntax". But a `mov` only moves the value that is the size of the operand. `%bl` is only one byte, so it only moves one byte. Any more than that wouldn't fit anyway, right? When you want to read the next byte, you have to increment `%esi` then do another `mov`.

Comment: Ok now i understand and i fix my code a little bit. Now everything working except conversion. How to conver all data in kodd to hex?